# IResourceChangeListener being called twice with one change

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, listener, changelistener

I'm using the IResourceChangeListener to listen for workspace/project changes. It's implemented as proposed by the Eclipse example:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IResourceChangeListener resourceChangeListener = new IResourceChangeListener() {
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Something changed!");
    }
};
workspace.addResourceChangeListener(resourceChangeListener, IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD);

// some time later on ...
workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(resourceChangeListener);
```

I implemented this code in a relatively new plugin project, but whenever changes are made in the workspace "Something changed!" is thrown twice?

If helpful: The class implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup`. `IResourceChangeListener` and `resourceChanged()` are created and inside of `earlyStartup()`.

Comment: Look at what you are told has changed in the IResourceChangeEvent. You are probably getting 'the file changed', 'the contents of this folder changed', 'the contents of this project changed'...

Comment: Now I can no longer reproduce the error. Looks like you magically solved my problem ;)
By using `event.getSource().getClass()` I get `class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace`. Which method would you have proposed for checking?

Comment: Could the problem be caused because I forgot to remove the IResourceChangeListener and thus had two of them running parallel? Or is the old IResourceChangeListener overwritten when recompiling my project?

Comment: You do need to remove old listeners

Comment: Is it possible to close them automatically on shutdown?
I had the idea of using a `IWorkbenchListener` but I think then the `IResourceChangeListener` is closed, but the `IWorkbenchListener` is still open after shutdown?

Comment: Everything is closed at shutdown.