# Plugin Development: IResourceChangeListener called more than once on just one change

Tags: eclipse, plugins, resources, listener

I am using IResourceChangeListener to listen to changes in resource.
my code is:

```
 public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

// Graph will hold all other objects
graph = new Graph(parent, SWT.NONE);

// create the graph with the right nodes and connections.
init();

//listen to changes in the resource.

workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
resourceChangeListener = new IResourceChangeListener() {
   public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
     //IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();

     Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         init();
         System.out.println("Something changed!"); 
         }
   });
   }
};
workspace.addResourceChangeListener(resourceChangeListener);

  }


  public void dispose() {
    workspace.removeResourceChangeListener(resourceChangeListener);

  }
```

But, when I am doing just one change in the resource, and save it, the listener called more than once! (usually twice, but sometimes even 6 times!!!)

I tried to use delta to see if it's called in the project,folder,file..
and I didn't saw differences between the calls (maybe I didn't used it properly).

I found this link, but I didn't found there solution to solve my problem
[IResourceChangeListener being called twice with one change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875766/iresourcechangelistener-being-called-twice-with-one-change)

How can I fix my code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do in the listener code to change how many resource change events you get. It depends entirely on how the code making the changes is doing the change.

You may find that `IResourceDelta.getKind` and `IResourceDelta.getFlags` return different values in the events. Also something `getMovedFromPath` and `getMovedToPath` for rename or move operations.

If it is your code doing the change you can use a `WorkspaceJob` or `WorkspaceModifyOperation` to do atomic changes to the workspace which will also reduce the number of resource change events.

You might also want to check that your old listeners are being removed correctly.

Comment: In all calls to listener, IResourceDelta.getKind return 4 and IResourceDelta.getFlags return 0. How could I check that old listeners being removed correctly? I remove it in dispose method. Where else I should remove it?

Comment: Just check that the remove is actually running, and check that only one instance of the listener is actually receiving results.